# How do I type a numpad plus-sign (+) with `pyautogui`?

Tags: python, pyautogui

For some GUI automation, I need to send a keystroke for the numpad plus-sign. (For some silly reason, the ancient software I'm interfacing with distinguishes between the numpad plus-sign and the top-row plus-sign...)

I can use `pyautogui.press('num1')` to send a `1` keystroke from the numpad, but `'num+'` and `'numplus'`, etc, don't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found that the `pyautogui.platformModule` contains the mappings for this. It varies based on your OS; Windows and Linux solutions are shown in the code block below -- something similar should be possible for Mac.

Similar keyboard mappings can be made for other keys. I couldn't find a good source for the Linux key mappings, but the windows ones can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

```
import pyautogui as gui

gui.platformModule.keyboardMapping.update({'numplus':gui.platformModule._display.keysym+_to_keycode(gui.platformModule.Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_Add'))}) # Linux: KP_Add found by random googling
gui.platformModule.keyboardMapping.update({'numplus':0x6B}) # Windows: VK_ADD from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
gui.press('numplus')
```

Note that `pyautogui.platformModule` comes from the file `_pyautogui_x11` or `_pyautogui_win`, etc, and is just aliased to `platformModule`.